# Showing database entries on a PHP calendar

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I'm creating a web-based booking system where a user can add bookings into a database, and the details stored in the database are (among others) "DateBooked, StartTime, EndTime, Room".

Here's the bit that pulls the relevant info for the day the user has clicked on from the database:
`$query="SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE DateBooked = '{$year}-{$selectedmonth}-{$selectedday}'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$todayarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

And the PHP:

```
$roomcount = 4;  
$room = 1;  
while ($room <= $roomcount)  
{  

echo "\n<div class=\"roomtimes\">";  

echo "\n<table border=1>";

echo "\n<tr><th class=\"titlecell\">Room $room</th></tr>";


$cellnum = 10;

while ( $cellnum < 23 )

    {

    echo "\n<tr>";

    echo "\n<td class=\"linkcell";

    if ($selectedtime==$cellnum)
        {

        echo " selectedcell";
        }

    echo "\">";

    echo "<a href=\"newbooking.php?m=$selectedmonth&d=$selectedday&t=$cellnum&r=$room\">$cellnum:00</a></td>";

    echo "\n</tr>";

    $cellnum++;

    }

    $room++;

echo "\n</table>";
echo "\n</div>";
}
```

So my question is, how can I add a bit of text saying "BOOKED" inside each table cell if a entry exists for that room and the number in that cell is in between the start time and end time of that booking?

I'm new to this site so let me know if I've done something wrong or you need more information, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to divide the cell content html and insert your "BOOKED" text there. And I suggest you use `mysql_fetch_assoc` so you get and associative array and it's easier to get the fields. If I'm understanding your code correctly you might be able to use something like this. This example is a replacement for the row that has the link output in it. I've used mysq_fetch_assoc here to get the StartTime and EndTime fields from the database. You might need to change the fields a bit depending in what data format they are.

```
echo "<a href=\"newbooking.php?m=$selectedmonth&d=$selectedday&t=$cellnum&r=$room\">$cellnum:00</a>";

if ($todayarray['StartTime'] <= $cellnum && $todayarray['EndTime'] >= $cellnum && $todayarray['Room'] == $room) echo 'BOOKED';

echo "</td>";
```

Comment: That makes sense - I'll have a go with that and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to be working. The database has multiple entries for each day, do I need a 'for' loop to check every single entry? I'm somewhat new to this as you may be able to tell. :-)

EDIT: Ignore that, I think it's a problem with the way I'm doing dates. I'll have a fiddle and let you know if it works

Comment: Yep it's the way I'm storing dates. Thank you for your help!